# Is this definition of an RSA modulus safe?

Tags: rsa

**Suggested definition**

A positive integer is a *safe RSA modulus* if, after removing all its prime factors less than 512 bits, it is composite and has size at least 2048 bits.

**Discussion**

I want to build the smallest-possible safe RSA modulus without a trusted party. (The use case is for an [RSA-based verifiable delay function](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/623.pdf) to be used on a blockchain.) The strategy is to randomly sample several random numbers $N_1, ..., N_k$ and multiply them together. Each $N_i$ has some probability $p$ of being a safe RSA modulus so the product $N_1...N_k$ has probability $1 - (1-p)^k$ of being safe.

The above strategy of multiplying randomly chosen integers was [pioneered by Thomas Sanders](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.4015&rep=rep1&type=pdf) in the context of RSA accumulators. He used a stricter definition of a safe RSA modulus which only looked at having at least two primes above a minimum bit size. The reasoning behind suggesting this less strict definition of a safe RSA modulus is to maximise the probability $p$ so as to minimise the size of the final RSA modulus.

The "512 bits" parameter was chosen (conservatively) to protect against the [ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) which has found primes of size [up to 273 bits](https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/records/top50.html). The "2048 bits" parameter was chosen (conservatively) to protect against the [GNSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) which factored numbers up to 768 bits.

Is the above definition of a safe RSA modulus actually safe to use in production?

Comment: A number with more than 2 prime factors is not an "RSA modulus" - in the general understanding of the term. Also, 2048 bit is not a conservative choice any more - it is the minimum of the latest BSI recommendation and it is not enough for the *near-term* recommendation of ECRYPT-CSA, which is 3K bit. See current recommendations on [keylength.com](https://www.keylength.com)

Comment: @tylo: actually, more than 2 prime factors is called "multiprime RSA", while not generally used, the concept is out there, and in fact, PKCS #1 has hooks for how to represent the private key in that case...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Overall I find the proposed definition and methods satisfactory in principle, barring quantum computers usable for factorization; but the 512-bit limit for factor, and to a lesser degree the 2048-bit unfactored limit, are not conservative.

---

### Unfactored limit

As noted in comment, for long term security or/and convincing security authorities, it's probably best to up the 2048-bit size to 3072-bit, or more. France's ANSSI changed mind and went from year 2020 to 2030 for the limit beyond which 2048-bit is no longer enough, but other authorities stick to earlier dates.

Difficulty of factoring $n$ by GNFS grows with $L_n\left[\frac1 3,\sqrt[3]{\frac{64}9}\right]$ in [L-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-notation), and (ignoring the hidden $o(1)$ term) that tells 2048-bit is roughly 40 Binary Orders of Magnitude (BOM) harder than the RSA-768 landmark of 2009. This is comfortable for now, but not huge. 3072-bit gives 62 BOM, that is huge.

---

### Small prime limit

Difficulty of factoring by ECM grows roughly as $L_p\left[\sqrt2,\frac1 2\right]$ where $p$ is the factor pulled. Neglecting the $o(1)$, that tells a 512-bit $p$ is roughly 28 BOM harder to pull by ECM than the 273-bit record of 2013. That does not look like a comfortable margin to me: [Ryan Propper's log](http://mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?s=f35dc2c8d894822d412bb21d8fec371b&p=352425#post352425) and account mention relatively modest resources compared to the RSA-768 effort:

> For this job, I did about 5,000 curves, spanning about 10 days, on the FarmShare compute cluster at Stanford. I guess this was quite the lucky find. :)

and I do not see that the latest theoretical advances ([Edwards curves](https://cr.yp.to/conferences/2005-sharcs/www.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/itsc/tanja/SHARCS/talks/ecm_paper.pdf)) have been used. Consider more effort, dedicated ASICs, Moore's law at 1 bit per year, and the 28 BOM is about gone. I would not go below 640-bit (>41 BOM) or 704-bit $p$ (>47 BOM) with 2048-bit $n$. 832-bit $p$ gives 59 BOM, that's large.

Comment: Are the $L_n\left[\frac1 3,\sqrt[3]{\frac{64}9}\right]$ and $L_p\left[\frac1 2,\sqrt2\right]$ difficulty growth rates proven lower bounds? Would you mind including sources for those?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if somebody finds a small (less than 512-bit in your case) prime factor $p$ of your modulus, then he can decrypt any ciphertext mod $p$. So in general it is not safe but it may be ok in your scenario.

Comment: With OAEP or similar Full Domain Hashing, getting the padded ciphertext modulo $p$ is not that helpful.